# sql to linq asp.net relations

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, relation

I have my dbml classes generated in my asp .net project.

I have a table called recepies and a table called components.

```
List<recepy> prods = db.recepies.Where(p => p.EndProd_id == id).ToList();
```

This is the line I use to get my records from database. I get the records I want so this command works just fine.

Now I want to enter my properties. No problem to enter my properties, unless I want to use a property linked to another table.
In my 'recepies' table I'm using an Id from my components table. When I look into my dbml, the link is present.

normally I should be able to get the property by the line

```
recepy.components.Id
```

except the 'components' isn't present as property... What did I do wrong?

thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: Could you add `recepy` and `component` definition from your .dbml file to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself..

Turns out that the table is in need of a primary key as well. wasn't the case in my table.